# QGIS 3.0 - Random Points w/in Polygon Expression

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon layer with 3 non-intersecting polygons(i.e., id=1, id=2, id=3). I'd like to randomly distribute 10 points within each of these polygon for 30 total, to be used as survey starting-points.

Qgis prompts to enter an expression that would define this; however, I'm pretty unfamiliar with the language required. If I remember correctly, previously versions allowed you to just specify the number of points per polygon?

The documentation on qgis is pretty scant here, so I may be missing something very obvious.

[image]

Comment: Expression means that you could define the count via a function (e.g. a different count for each polygon, which is defined in the polygons attributes). What happens if you simply type "10"?

Comment: Ah, whelp, that was easy enough :/

Comment: What if you're using Point Density? The Expression box is still required :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type `10` into the expression :)

Comment: @AlexM - Most welcome, glad it helped :)